# Tapatalk attempts to open gaming.stackechange on android

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-site, browser-support

I was Googling on my S7 for the best way to level conjuration in Skyrim, and wanted to open the gaming.stackexchange result. However, when I clicked on the link, Tapatalk opened instead of my browser, but it never showed any results.

Is there supposed to be a link with Tapatalk? Or should Tapatalk be contacted to fix this? I don't need it fixed myself.

I only thought to mention it here because it could affect other users, and if those users don't get to gaming.stackexchange that means a loss of ad revenue and exposure for this site.

I'm not interested in a technical fix for me personally.
I crossposted on [tapatalk forums](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/tapatalksupport/viewtopic.php?f=93&t=39500) that this is an issue.

Comment: What makes you think this is an SE problem? I see no reason to believe this is an issue with anything but Tapatalk. We are not third party app support.

Comment: Yea, I get that. But if all mobile users who happen to have taptalk installed cant get to gaming.stackexchange.com on mobile, that means less visitors, less ad revenue. Which might be of concern to Stack Exchange, who might want to get gamers to come here on mobile whilst they are gaming. I just thought I'd report it here that it happens. I couldn't care less about how to fix it. I just wanted to report it.

Comment: *[status-declined]* - As Frank stated, Tapatalk is a third-party browser/app. Not much that SE can do with this bug

Answer (score 2):

Tapatalk is a third party browser. It not functioning properly with a site is the app's problem, not SE's.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have the Tapatalk app configured to automatically open web links (either deliberately or inadvertently), which is why it's attempting to open when you click a link, rather than the link opening in your browser. You'll have to dig through the application settings on your device to change this to 'Prompt me to choose an application' or choose a different application as the default.

As for why Tapatalk doesn't work, well, there's not much we can do. There is a FAQ question on Meta Stack Exchange which covers which browsers (and browser versions) are supported:

> ### Which browsers are supported?
>
> So here's the bottom line for this question: **we support the last two versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use**. This does not include beta/dev releases, which are not supported.
> <sub>[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/179041) - Meta Stack Exchange</sub>

In terms of mobile devices, the latest versions of these browsers have been confirmed working:

- Android browser
- Mobile Safari (iPhone browser)
- Internet Explorer Mobile
- Firefox for Mobile
- Chrome
- Opera Mobile

There is a full list of compatible and incompatible browsers on the linked FAQ.

Comment: Tapatalk usually only opens fora it is connected with/that use the tapatalk api. No clue why they have gaming.stackoverflow.com in their trigger list. Theres no setting in the app itself.